# How to add Sound Effect on clicking an image in gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-image

I am using a gridview that contain some images. I want to add sound effect on clicking each image in the gridview. I added images in res/raw folder and added the following code.

```
MediaPlayer mp;
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,int position,long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ok);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                 "Shape Matched",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.TestShapeActivity2"));
        } else {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.no);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Please Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //startActivity(new Intent("com.example.TestShapeActivity2"));
        }
    }
});
```

But the create function gives the error

```
The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int).
```

Please help me.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the two calls to

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ok);
```

to

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestShapeActivity.this, R.raw.ok);
```

or whatever the name of the activity you are in is.

`create()` takes a `Context` but when you refer to `this` within the `OnItemClickListener` it is referring to the listener, not the activity.

Learn more about the `this` keyword [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Comment: You should also start the mediaplayer by calling `.start()`

Comment: Did so. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use SoundPool as it will sound less laggy;
first declare your SoundPool:

```
     private SoundPool soundPool;
     private int sound1;
```

Load the sound in onCreate: The first number set how many sounds can queue for reproduction.

```
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    sound1 = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.msound, 1);
```

Finally in your OnClick:

```
soundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

This last method is like this: `play(int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)` This allows you to set how many times it will reproduce, etc..

[More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

EDIT:

```
grid.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int pos, long arg3) {
    soundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1); 
    ...
```

just the same for item click:

```
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,long arg3) {
    soundPool.play(soundPulsa, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
...
```

Comment: Thank you. But will it work in case of images or gridview? I am using onItemClickListener and onItemClick...Neron T

Comment: i use it in a gridview with 25 images and it works fine. posted how it is called in my answer (edited)